# MAC binding specific Sub Domain with HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess

I want to bind a specific MAC to a specific subdomain address. I am now using this code for a specific IP. But now I want to use a specific MAC address.

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
SetEnvIf CF-Connecting-IP "^103\.111\.227\.224$" ALLOWED_IP=1
SetEnvIf CF-Connecting-IP "^146\.70\.191\.237$" ALLOWED_IP=2
Require env ALLOWED_IP
```

This .htccess is working, but I want. MAC instead of IPs.

Comment: You can't use MAC in Apache configs.

Comment: yup only IPs are working